# A new array out of some values from existing array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop

If I got an array like:

`string[] test = new string[5] { "hello", "world", "test", "world", "world"};`

How can I make a new array out of the ones that is the same string, "world" that is where you on before hand know how many there are, here 3?

I was thinking of something like:

```
string[] newArray = new string[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (test[i].Contains("world"))
            {
                newArray[i] = test[i];
            }
        }
```

The problem is here: `newArray[i] = test[i];`

Since it's iterating from 0 to 4, there's gonna be an error since newArray is limited to 3.

How do solve this?

EDIT: I need it to be that from test (the old array) position 1, 3 and 4 should be stored at 0, 1 and 2 in the newArray.

Comment: Could you write the output you want exactly as you did for the input? It would help us (at least me) to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: @CédricBignon I would like the output to be something like "newArray contains the following strings: world, world, world". Is that how you meant?

Comment: @Erik It was more like `string[] output = new string[3] { "world", "world", "world"}`. What do you want as output for the following input `{ "hello", "world", "hello", "hello", "test", "my world", "world"}`?

Comment: @Erik: that's exactly what the 2 answers with 0 upvotes tried to do from the start. Not sure if that's what you actually want though.

Comment: Then I'd want `string[] output = new string[3] { "world", "world", "world"}` since it's still 3 strings that contains "world". Thanks.

Comment: @Erik: So why don't you accept one of the answers then?

Comment: Ideally you need a histogram collection, telling you how many of each string exists in the original array. There is no default implementation, but some are available online if you look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same index `i` for both `test` and `newArray`. I would suggest you create another counter variable and increment it:

```
string[] newArray = new string[3];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (test[i].Contains("world"))
    {
        newArray[counter] = test[i];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Erik - this will work, I would also extend this further and break out of the for loop if counter is >= newArray.Length

Comment: I'm sorry again. I misread, it's late here, hehe. Your logic is correct, I'll see if I can apply this logic.

Comment: Accepted this as it was the simplest applicable and working solution in my case, even though most answers will work just as great (and some even better).

Answer (score 5):

You want to use Linq:

```
var newArray = test.Where(x => x.Contains("world")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `List<string>` instead:

```
    List<string> newList = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (test[i].Contains("world"))
        {
            newList.Add(test[i]);
        }
    }
```

If you really need it as an array later.. convert the list:

```
string[] newArray = newList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

With an extra helper index variable

```
    string[] newArray = new string[3];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (test[i].Contains("world"))
        {
            newArray[j++] = test[i];
            if (j >= newArray.Length)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this won't work if there are more than 3 strings with "world". edit: didn't see that the question said you already know there are 3

Comment: @Alden: well that was his requirement, not mine. He defined array at 3. Read his question conditions, I am just answering.

Comment: or more than 5 elements in the array, and OP says if his array was like that, meaning thats not his actual data

Comment: @Alden The question said, "where you on before hand know how many there are, here 3".

Comment: I wonder if anyone still reads OP questions here, since the only 2 answers that did read it, have 0 upvotes.

Comment: Personally I think its awful coding including two for loops in the same line as you have. I also still don't think your code would work if there were suddenly 4 "worlds", OP would have to update this code which is just tedious and error prone

Comment: @Ma3x for loops with mulitple index variables are incredibly hard to read. unless you're trying to optimize milliseconds away, there's no reason not to use linq. even if you know how many words contain "world", it's cleaner and more readable to use linq.

Comment: Yeah I know all that. I do that myself, but here we were specifically answering OP's question. How to solve a problem with one index when filling 2 different sized arrays.

Comment: @Ma3x to quote OP: "How can I make a new array out of the ones that is the same string, 'world'". OP _suggested_ solving the problem by using one index to fill two different sized arrays, and asked the community to help out.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't technically your question but if you wish to make a load of arrays based of those with the same word you could do

```
test.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();
```

this will give you a List of Lists.. with your test data this will be

```
list1 - hello
list2 - world world world
list3 - test
```

Example use

```
var lists =  test.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();
foreach(var list in lists)
{
     foreach(var str in list)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(str);
     } 
     Console.WriteLine();
}
```